# android app set up file sharing

Tags: java, android, xml, file-sharing

I have been working through the Android developer tutorial to send data. This question is with regards to sending binary content.
I have set up my MainActivity.java file's sendMessage() method as such:

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {       
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriToImage);
        shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
}
```

I have set up my AndroidManifest.xml file to include a  tag that grants URI permissions and locates the resource @xml/file_paths (.../xml/file_paths.xml). I have set up .../file_paths.xml to as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <files-path name="send_images" path="images/"/>
    </paths>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

This .xml file references an files/images/ directory and a send_images directory to append to the fileprovider authority. I haven't created a files/images directory, which is the source of my confusion. The tutorial says that they are part of the internal storage area. What is that? Where would I set up these directories? Are the supposed to be created at/during runtime or loaded into the app at compile time?

Comment: Take some help from [here](http://androhub.com/android-share-text-and-images-using-share-intent/).

Answer (score 0):

> I have set up .../file_paths.xml to as such:

I do not know why you have a `<PreferenceScreen>` element there. If you are using `FileProvider`, the root element of your XML resource needs to be the `<paths>` element.

> The tutorial says that they are part of the internal storage area. What is that?

[Internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) is a private area of the on-board flash for your app.

> Where would I set up these directories?

There is only one directory referred to in that XML: `images/`. Given that you are using a `<files-path>` element, that `images/` refers to a subdirectory of `getFilesDir()`, as is covered in [the documentation for `FileProvider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html#SpecifyFiles).

> Are the supposed to be created at/during runtime or loaded into the app at compile time?

You can only put files in internal storage at runtime.